# TTLauncherItem show in second page

Tags: iphone, icons, ttlauncherview, ttlauncheritem

I have a TTLauncherView in my app,and I set the columnCount=3,When I have 9 TTLauncherItem,they all show in the first page,but when I have 10 items or more,how can I let them show in the second page automatic?

Answer (score 0):

They are shown in the second page automatically.